Causal Effect in DAG with two alternative scenarios
I am trying to understand DAGs and I am not sure I am getting it right.
I hope somebody here can help.
Let's say I have the following scenario:
When the weather is good, the employees of a company walk home. I don't know what happens on the way home, but many have a bad hangover the day after. I suspect they stop at a bar, but cannot observe that.
When the weather is bad, the employees take the company bus and go directly home. I don't know what they do at home, but the day after some (less than on good weather days) have a hangover.
I would like to calculate the average causal effect (ACE) of walking home on getting drunk. And I would like to understand if it can be calculated from statistical association alone (using Pearl's calculus rules).
I am not sure I understand how (if) weather comes into play or not, considering it is somehow random and considering only one of the two scenarios (walking or bus) can take place on a given day.
I thought about this DAG:

But I would like to consider the possibility that drinking in a bar has the effect of increasing the chance to (continue to) drink at home.
Something like these, maybe?

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I find texts on DAGs very complicated, and the number of examples limited.

If all you are interested in is the average causal effect of "walking home" on "drunk", it doesn't matter which version of the DAG you are using. You would only have to adjust for "weather" to estimate it in an unbiased fashion. What matters is that you close all backdoor paths by adjusting for covariates. In the first DAG, "drinking together at a bar" would be the only mediator for that average causal effect, while in the second DAG "drinking alone at home" would be a second mediator. It does not matter that you don't observe them though, if youre just interested in the effect you specified.

Thanks!
However, if I adjust for Rain, I have to condition on an empty set. Formula (taking "D"=Drunk, "W"=walk and "R"=Rain):
$$ ACE = P\left( D | do\left( W=1 \right)\right) - P\left( D | do\left( W=0 \right)\right) $$ Where:
$$P\left( D | do\left( W=1 \right)\right) = P\left( D | W=1, R=1 \right)*P(R=1) +
P\left( D | W=1, R=0 \right)*P(R=0)
$$
W=1 and R=1 cannot happen because with Rain employees walk home.
What can I do in this case?
How would the situation change if instead of Rain I have some other random assignment process (that I cannot control/observe)?
